# What are the most frequent steps an Objective-C programmer will go through to refactor his code?

Tags: objective-c, refactoring

Are there frequent processes which the programmer will go through? Or does everyone have different coding habits?

Answer (score 1):

Often when it looks like I will be repeating some code or algorithm that I already have, I look for ways to avoid it.

A common one for me is to have need for a class that is similar in some way to a class I already have. I break the original class into a superclass (with the common functionality) and  a derived class, and use the superclass as the basis for my second class.